# compiled typescript code not working with certain package

Tags: typescript, tsc

Whenever i try to compile and run my typescript program I get this error:

`Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\project\node_modules\pocketbase\dist\pocketbase.es.mjs not supported. Instead change the require of C:\project\node_modules\pocketbase\dist\pocketbase.es.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.`

It is caused by the package not supporting require but the compiled code using require anyways.

my tsconfig.json is attached below:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "es6",
    "strict": false,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist/",
    "baseUrl": "./src/"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "./node_modules",
    "./node_modules/*",
    "./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

I have tried changing my tsconfig.json a few times expecting it to fix the issue. But it has not resolved the issue.